# Disambiguate pointer to overloaded const member functions and member operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a small class with the following member functions:

```
class Point3 {
    Point3 operator - (Point3 const & p) const {...} 
    Point3 operator - () const {...}

    const float &x() const {...}
    float& x() {...}
}
```

I need to pass these member functions as arguments to other functions, and of course using just `&Point3::operator-` and `&Point3::x` does not work.

Looking to similar questions online, I concluded that the syntax for making this kind of casts is `(ReturnType (Class::*)(Args...)) &Class::Function`. However, I tried for the binary operator - without success.

```
(Point3 (Point3::*)(Point3 const &)) &Point3::operator-
```

gives `error: address of overloaded function 'operator-' does not match required type 'Point3 (const Point3 &)' note: candidate function has different qualifiers (expected unqualified but found 'const') [...]`

For the `x()` member function I just don't have idea on where place the const related to the member function. How can I disambiguate these member functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler was nice enough to tell you what exactly is wrong. You forgot `const`:

```
(Point3 (Point3::*)(Point3 const &) const) &Point3::operator-
//                                  ^~~~~
```

And for `x` (I assume you want the `const` overload):

```
(const float &(Point3::*)() const) &Point3::x
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! I tried all the day to place that const everywhere except in its right place :D Thanks again!